# Confusion with usage of defer attribute

Tags: javascript, deferred

Say if I have 3 scripts on my webpage, a (jquery), b and c, where script b depends on script a, and script c depends on both scripts a and b.

(Although not practical?) script c is included, with some other HTML and php code, with a php `include()` command resulting in it appearing first.

Thus, the following order is produced

```
<script (inline code)> //c - depends on 'a' and 'b'
<script (link to jquery)> //a - depends on nothing
<script (link to file on server)> //b - depends on a
```

I would of thought that the following would work

```
<script defer (inline code)> //c - depends on 'a' and 'b'
<script async (link to jquery)> //a - depends on nothing
<script async (link to file on server)> //b - depends on a
```

But i still get an error from script 'c' saying: `webpage.php:139 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

for the line
`$('document').ready(function() {`

Does script 'c' HAVE to be placed at the end of `webpage.php` or is there a way around this? If so, why?

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) of _defer_ on MDN states that: **This attribute must not be used if the src attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts), in this case it would have no effect.**

Comment: @MaxG ohhhhhh... That makes sense, does this mean that we can only fix this by placing the inline code at the end or having the, currently inline, code in a separate file?

Comment: Yes, that's what you have to do, as far as I know.